# How to update newly added column to back fill the data for old records

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table vehicle with columns id, model, colour, is_default.
in this is_default is a newly added column and we have 4000 old recored before adding is_primary.

the default value for is_primary is 0.

I want to fill this column for all the present records in such a way that

1. A model can have multiple colours, but can only have one colour as is_default = 1. All others will be false (0).
2. If a model already has a default colour then the query should not touch any records related to that model

Note: We have 1000 models and 50 colours possible

I tried below solution

```
UPDATE
vehicle AS scl
JOIN (
    SELECT model, MIN(id) AS min_id
    FROM vehicle 
    WHERE is_default = 0 
    GROUP BY model) AS sc 
ON scl.model sc2.model AND scl.id= sc2.min_id 
SET scl.is_default = 1;
```

but when I execute this it updates records which already have a default colour.

Comment: Is the column name `is_default` or `is_primary`?

Comment: hey man, I expected confusion, MY BAD, consider anything just that the purpose is the same

Comment: "but when I execute this it updates records which already have a default colour"  Of course it will update everything.  You don't put a `WHERE` on your update so it will update every single record.

Comment: can you please update the solution here, that will be helpful.
thanks really appriciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause isn't excluding the entire model when `is_default = 1`, it's just ignoring those rows when finding `MIN(id)` for the model. Use a subquery to exclude all the rows with that model.

```
UPDATE
vehicle AS scl
JOIN (
    SELECT model, MIN(id) AS min_id
    FROM vehicle AS v
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM vehicle AS v1
        WHERE v1.model = v.model AND v1.is_default = 1
    )
    GROUP BY model) AS sc 
ON scl.model = sc.model AND scl.id= sc.min_id 
SET scl.is_default = 1;
```

Comment: what is your sc2 ?
as you have used sc2 in below line
ON scl.model sc2.model AND scl.id= sc2.min_id

Comment: I just copied that part from your code, I didn't notice that you hadn't assigned the alias.

Comment: I've changed `sc2` to `sc`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
UPDATE Vehicle v
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ID, CASE WHEN row_number() over (partition by model order by case when is_default = 1 then 0 else 1 end, colour) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END New_Default
  FROM Vehicle
) p ON p.id = v.id
SET IS_DEFAULT = New_Default
```

See it here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/pq-rMtap

However, it will set *every row*... just to the same existing value in cases where that is desired. The trick there is using the `ORDER BY` within the window to sort the current default first.